# How to change font style and size of subtitles in Celluloid?

Tags: video-player, subtitle, mpv-media-player

How to change **font family**, **font size**, or even **font color** for subtitles in **Celluloid**? There are no relevant options in the settings (*Preferences*) like in VLC or Totem.

Answer (score 9):

Celluloid has no point-and-click option in the settings to change the styling of subtitles (as of yet, maybe), but since it is a frontend for **mpv**, it can use [mpv (command line) options](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#subtitles), including those for subtitles:

### Method 1: Put the options in Celluloid's Preferences

- From [this](https://github.com/celluloid-player/celluloid/issues/187#issuecomment-225176692): Open Celluloid and go to *Preferences* → *Miscellaneous* tab.
- Put the relevant subtitles options in the *Extra MPV options* box (if there are more than one option, separate each one with a space). For example:

  ```
  --sub-font=Tahoma --sub-font-size=48 --sub-color=1.0/1.0/0.0
  ```

  This sets the default font to `Tahoma`, font size to `48` (against a window height of 720), font color to yellow (255,255,0).
- Hit *Save* and restart Celluloid.

This method is pretty fast and convenient, but it has a major **drawback**: it will **not** apply the options containing quotation marks (`"` or `'`), which are required for font types with spaces in their names or for using color value in hex form (which is way easier than having to convert RGB 0-255 to RGB 0.0-1.0). For example, this line will **not** be applied:

```
--sub-font='Comic Sans MS' --sub-color='#FFFF00'
```

That brings us to the 2nd method.

### Method 2: Load an external config file into Celluloid

- Create a file named `mpv.conf` in `~/Documents` or wherever (or in `~/.config/mpv/` if also using mpv separately)
- Put the relevant options into the file, without the double dash (`--`). For example:

  ```
  # Font type
  sub-font='Comic Sans MS'
  # Font size
  sub-font-size=48
  # Font color
  sub-color='#FFFF00'
  # Font format  
  sub-bold=yes
  sub-italic=no
  # Text background/box (black with 75% alpha) 
  sub-back-color='#C0000000'
  ```
- Save the file.
- Open Celluloid and go to *Preferences* → *Config Files* tab.
- Check *Load MPV configuration file* and browse to the `mpv.conf` file just created.
- Hit *Save* and restart Celluloid.

**Note**: If both the config file and the *Extra MPV options* box are used, options in the box will take priority. For example, if there are `--sub-font=Tahoma` and `sub-font='Comic Sans MS'`, the font will be `Tahoma`.

With the power of mpv, one can even set *custom keyboard shortcuts* for subtitles. For example, to set key bindings for changing the sub font size and text background size:

- Create a file named `input.conf` in `~/Documents` or wherever (or in `~/.config/mpv/` if also using mpv separately)
- Put these lines in the file (based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490232)):

  ```
  # Increase sub font size (set to [Alt] + [k])
  ALT+k add sub-font-size +1
  # Decrease sub font size (set to [Alt] + [j])
  ALT+j add sub-font-size -1 
  # Increase sub text background size (set to [Alt] + [.])
  ALT+. add sub-shadow-offset +1
  # Increase sub text background size (set to [Alt] + [,])
  ALT+, add sub-shadow-offset -1
  ```
- Save the file.
- Open Celluloid and go to *Preferences* → *Config Files* tab.
- Check *Load MPV input configuration file* and browse to the `input.conf` file just created.
- Hit *Save* and restart Celluloid.

Comment: Hey, good Q&A! I wonder how to set command line format "LEFT seek 5" (I know config file, I found 1st way more convenient for me)? Thanx!

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov as far as I know, there's no command line option for that. From [mpv's manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#interactive-control): `User input.conf files and Lua scripts can define additional key bindings.`. Other than this, I haven't found any details about another way to map keys to input commands. You might want to double-check the manual, though.